# CakePHP 4 Is it possible limit result in view using Paginator helper?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am able to limit pagination result in controller

```
$this->paginate = ['limit'=>2];

$products = $this->paginate($this->Products);
```

Now a scenario I need to limit result in `view file`.Using paginator helper is it possible to limit data in view ?

Comment: The paginator helper can't do such things, no, you'd have to actually do the pagination calculations and query building in the view layer. To be sure that this isn't an [**xy question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/227568), why do you need to paginate in the view?

Comment: I have a products view page. Where I need to view all products using pagination also there has a portion called latest products. Where I will show 5 products. I am trying to do it using single query.

Comment: You can use `array_slice()` on generated result.